# Using raw literal representations when working with variable strings

Tags: python, string-literals

I am trying to use a for loop to copy files in different source folders into the same destination folder. I like to use literal representations to avoid issues with multiple backslashes in the file paths. I could not find the proper way to get a literal representation of a variable. Any tip would be appreciated. The code is below:

```
import shutil
destination_folder=DF

for i in range (1,3):
    new_folder='folder_'+str(i)
    new_path=os.path.join('C:\foo', new_folder, file_to_copy)
    source_file= r(new_path)                #WRONG
    destination= r(destination_folder)      #WRONG
    shutil.copy(source_file, destination)
```

Comment: I think you mean `r'C:\data'` in your code, no?

Comment: Today's moment of Zen: Variables already contain their contents.

Comment: It would be r'C:\data\folder_1\file_to_copy'

Comment: As a side note, `C:\data` is a bad example to use, because it happens to work the same with or without a raw string literal, because `\d` isn't a Python escape sequence. Try `C:\foo` or `C:\noway` instead.

Comment: corrected with C:\foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r` is not a function that applies to string objects, it's a modifier that applies to string literals. It changes how the literal gets interpreted as a value. But once it's done, the value is just a plain old string value. In particular:

```
>>> a = '\n'
>>> b = '''
... '''
>>> a == b
True
```

So, if `a` and `b` are the same value, how can Python possibly know that you want to turn it into `r'\n'`?

For that matter, imagine this:

```
>>> c = sys.stdin.readline()

>>> c == a
True
```

Or this:

```
>>> d = chr(10)
>>> d == a
```

You can't go back and re-interpret the string literal as a raw string in any of these other cases—in `b` it would be unchanged, and in `c` and `d` there was no string literal in the first place.

---

If you want to escape *all* special characters in a string value, without caring where they came from, you can do that by asking Python to escape the string. For example:

```
>>> e = a.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii')
```

But you definitely don't want to do that for constructing filenames to pass to the `shutil.copy` function.

---

If you have a string literal in your code, and you want it to be treated as a raw string literal, just write it as a raw string literal. So:

```
new_path=os.path.join(r'C:\foo', new_folder, file_to_copy)
source_file= new_path
destination= destination_folder
```

You could instead manually escape the backslash in your literal, or use forward slashes instead of backslashes, etc. But those are all things you do *to the literal* before it gets evaluated by Python, not *to the string* after the fact.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The code above, however, does not resolve my problem. As I am working through this, it occurs to me that maybe my real problem here is not r (at this point it looks like I was on the wrong path) but rather the shutil.copy command. It keeps giving me an error message because it cannot find the files (because of double backslashes being inserted into the filepath that I created above). Any tip would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @user1609104: I suspect there are no double backslashes being inserted into the file path, and that you're actually just confusing the `repr` of the string with the string itself (in the same way you originally confused the string literal with the string itself). But without seeing the actual code that you ran and the output you saw that led you to that conclusion, I can't do any more than guess.

Comment: thanks, through this conversation I resolved the issue. the way I did it was simply converting the fwd slashes into back slashes and keep using the shutil.copy command as in the initial version of the code. What worked for me is the following:                 import shutil
destination_folder=DF

for i in range (1,3):
    new_folder='folder_'+str(i)
    new_path=os.path.join(r'C:/foo', new_folder, file_to_copy)             
    source_file=source_path
    source_file=source_file.replace('\\','/')
    shutil.copy(source_file, destination)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a "literal representation" of a variable string doesn't really make sense.

If you have a variable called `new_path`, the value of this variable is simply a string value. The `r` prefix only applies to string literals.

Comment: My problem is that if I don't use literals, then the shutil.copy command gives me issues because it adds backslashes to the file path.

Comment: @user1609104: No, it doesn't.

Comment: When I use the shutil.copy command as written in the previous code (i.e. shutil.copy(source_file, destination), I get an error message (IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:...) and the name of the file path contains double backslashes

Comment: Ah, you are seeing double backslashes because that is the way Python prints things out.  Type `r'\n'` into the Python shell.  It will respond with `'\\n'`  But take the length of that string.  It is 2, not 3.  It never added a backslash; it is just _showing_ you the result in the double-backslash form.